# how to change navigation bar color for the current view controller only

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am wondering how i can set the nav bar color for current VC only, without using `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` pairs. These pair of functions are hard to maintain because it split the logic into 2 places.

I have seen multiple SO answers, but they change the whole navigation bar item throughout all VCs in the nav stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different solutions comes to my mind.

1. Implement custom NavigationBar for that ViewController
2. Use a base ViewController to override NavigationBar color in each controller

I would prefer the second way, and here is an example:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // Set one color as default and override this property in each view controller that you want to change navigation bar color
    var navigationBarColor: UIColor {
        return .red
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = navigationBarColor
    }
}

class FirstViewController: BaseViewController {

    override var navigationBarColor: UIColor {
        return .blue
    }
    
    // Do your stuff
}

class SecondViewController: BaseViewController {
    
    override var navigationBarColor: UIColor {
        return .green
    }
    
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: this is smart! each vc only needs to care how to customize its own nav bar. It's sort of like `navigationItem` design